# How to make a death screen without making it a new state?

Tags: screen

You must be confused by the question, let me explain. In some games, when you die, it shows a death screen but the background is sometimes transparent and shows the game play. how to do that. here are a few pictures to help out:
And sorry for advertising

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep the game playing behind UI overlay. If you have some AI, which is dependent on player's presence, then do something like this:

```
private void Update() {
  if (player.isAlive) {
    UpdateAI();
  }
}
```

If your enemies are based on FSM, make a new "Wonder" state, in which they act as if there was nobody to attack. Things not dependent on player, should work correctly after player's death.

Comment: My game has no AI, so what your trying to say is that, when my player dies, just put a UI overlay on the gamestate. correct me if im wrong. btw Im just 13 so please go easy on me. Thnx!

Comment: Yes. I mentioned AI, because that's really the only thing that needs the player to exist.